# Rails - How to create multiple "matches" in one action between a user and opportunities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I'm looking for the easiest and the most clever way to create interest_id(match) in one-click.

Here is my MVC :

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :interests, through: :opportunities
end
```

interest.rb

```
class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :opportunity
  belongs_to :user
end
```

opportunity.rb

```
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :interests
end
```

InterestsController.rb

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @opportunities = Opportunity.all
  @interest = Interest.new(interest_params)
  if @interest.save!
    redirect_to user_interests_path, notice: 'it works'
  else
    render :new, notice:"it doesn't work"
  end
end

def interest_params
  params.permit(
    :user_id,
    :opportunity_id)
end
```

user/show

```
<%= link_to "Match", user_interests_path(@user), class:"btn btn-primary", :method => :post %>
```

For now, I can't pass opportunities (nil). Could you please advise me about the easiest way to create interests? (New on RoR for 6 months). 
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to use a link instead of a form with checkboxes?

Comment: How `Interest` can have `opportunity_ids` if it belongs to (one) `Opportunity` ?

Comment: At term, I would like to generate Interest automatically, on callbacks. Exact for opportunity_ids, I'm editing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your relation schema, the `Interest` is the join record associating a `User` to (eventually) many `Opportunity`, and vice-versa (many-to-many relationship).

With that being said (and please correct me if I am wrong), you can do the following to achieve what you want:

```
# in user/show
<% @opportunities.each do |opportunity| %>
  <%= 
    link_to "Match opportunity #{opportunity.id}",
      user_interests_path(@user, opportunity_id: opportunity.id),
      class: "btn btn-primary",
      method: :post
  %>
<% end %>

# in interests_controller
def create
  if current_user.interests.create(opportunity_id: opportunity_id_param)
    redirect_to user_interests_path, notice: 'it works'
  else
    render :new, notice: "it doesn't work"
  end
end

private

def opportunity_id_param
  params.require(:opportunity_id)
end
```

This suggested code:

- requires the `opportunity_id` param for the `interests#create` action
- use `current_user` to automatically set the `user_id` on the `Interest` model, so the end-users can't send a `user_id` that are not theirs (if they could, then each user could create interest for other users without their agreement... security flaw)

---

On a side note, **I strongly advise you to not select all** existing `Opportunity` record and display it on your page: it does not scale. Someday, you will end up with hundreds of `Opportunity` records, making this list too big from a User Experience perspective.

I suggest a smarter approach, for example some kind of ordering + limit: max of `10` records ordered by "most interest", which can be accomplished by the following:

```
# in controller
@popular_opportunities = Opportunity
  .joins('LEFT JOINS interests ON interests.opportunity_id = opportunities.id')
  .order('count(interests.*) DESC, opportunities.id')
  .limit(10)
```

And then in the view, simply use `@populator_opportunities` instead of `@opportunities`.

Other options, like pagination, are also efficient in this case but IMO relevant ordering is the minimum.

Comment: Exact. It seems to work. I have just an undefined method 'fetch' for string which just appeared when clicked but it generated the good numbers of buttons.

Comment: @Maceoz I updated my answer with the fixed code. I was not expecting that `ActionController::Parameters.new(a: 1).require(:a)` would return the value, but a copy of the hash with only allowed/required key/value pairs

Comment: Thank you ! I'm on the way, I can now see the opportunity_id in the parameters. An other error appeared but due to my nested associations (HasManyThroughNestedAssociations). Probably a problem on my models (has_many like suggested by Alan).

Comment: @Maceoz yes, a `User` `has_many :interests` and therefore it also `has_many :opportunities, through: :interests`

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to pass the ids of the opportunities you want to create interest some way, the best is a form, with checkboxes like MrShemek said, or a multi select dropdown.

I think you probably made some mistakes in User and Opportunity with the has_many and belong_to part:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :interests
   has_many :opportunities, through: :interests
   # interest is the one that links user and opportunity, it has the references for both user and opportunities
end
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :interests
   has_many :users, through: :interests
 end
```

then in controller you could do

```
def create
   @user = current_user
   @opportunities = Opportunity.all
   @user.opportunity_ids = interest_params[:opportunity_ids] # it will create the interrests automatically for the given ids (because the relations of has_many through)
   if @user.save!
      redirect_to user_interests_path, notice: 'it works'
   else
      render :new, notice:"it doesn't work"
   end
end
```

Comment: the ids writers are dangerous. they have persistence effect: `User.first.opportunity_ids = []` will actually trigger `DELETE` statements without even running validations or callbacks, and still do it even though you did not `save` the user object. Yep, that's crazy, I know... Don't use `_ids` generated methods on update (because it works properly on create)